# Is it possible to detect a space at the end of an argument with a bash function?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a bash function that looks like this:

```
test5() { echo $#; }
```

I want to be able to detect when there is a space after the last argument.

For example, running this (quotes show to illustrate whitespace): `"test5 test"` produces: `1` while `"test5 test "` also produces `1`. I would like to detect when there is a space after test.

Thank you!

Comment: `[[ "test5 test " =~ \ $ ]] && echo "trailing space"`

Comment: You can't: thanks to [Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting), all leading/trailing whitespace is thrown away. You would only be able to detect this if the user entered `test5 test ""`

Comment: @glennjackman: In the context of Bash, "word splitting" means something specific, which isn't relevant to this question. Rather, this is just the generic "Breaks the input into words and operators" step at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Operation.

Comment: No I mean word splitting. From the manual: "sequences of<space>, <tab>, and <newline> at the beginning and end of the results of the previous expansions are ignored". The test5 function can not know if there were trailing spaces.

Comment: I'll also reference section 2 Definitions for "word" and "metacharacter" and section 3.7.1 Simple Command Expansion

"the remaining words are the arguments."

Answer (score -1):

Won't work from commandline. May work in script:

```
#/bin/bash
test5(){
    [[ $(sed ${BASH_LINENO[0]}'!d;/ $/!d' <"${BASH_SOURCE[1]}") ]] &&
    echo called with trailing whitespace

    echo $#;
}

test5 5 args no trailing spaces
test5 5 args three trailing spaces   
test5 "1 arg no trailing spaces     "
```